# Basic question about G-coverings

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, group-actions, covering-spaces

Given a topological space $X$, and a group $G$ acting on $X$,
I don't understand why the projection $\pi:X\to X/G$ isn't a covering map if the action of $G$ has fixed points. In other words I don't understand why if, given a covering map $p:E \to Y$, the action of $\mathrm{Aut}(E,p)$ must not have fixed points in order to have $Y\simeq E/\mathrm{Aut}(E,p)$. It's clear to me that if the action of $G=\mathrm{Aut}(E,p)$ has no fixed points then $E\simeq Y\times G$; however even if the action has some fixed points, we can glue every two points $e_1, e_2\in E$ if there is some $g\in G$ such that $e_1=ge_2$. After this process we obtain the space $Y$, and this should mean that $Y\simeq E/G$. Where am I wrong? Maybe we can't glue the points without "ripping" the space $E$? Thank you very much

Comment: Note that if $g(x) = x$ for $g \neq 0$ and some $x \in X$ then the action cannot be *proper*, in the sense that for any open $x \in U$ you have $g(U) \cap U \neq \emptyset$ with $g \neq id$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It's clear to me that if the action has no fixed point then $E\simeq Y\times G$ " : that's really far from true; if it were, coverings would be really uninteresting.

Think about $\mathbb Z$ acting on $\mathbb R$ by translation for instance.

The problem is that, although $E/G$ still exists the projection map $E\to E/G$ is not a covering in general (it can be : if $G$ acts trivially, it has tons of fixed points and $E=E/G$ so $E\to E/G$ is a covering map).

To understand why that is, consider $\mathbb Z/2$ acting on $\mathbb R$ by $-1$ : $0$ is a fixed point, and the quotient is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R_+$, with projection map $x\mapsto |x|$. Now $0\in \mathbb R_+$ has no neighbourhood that lifts to a homeomorphic neighbourhood in $\mathbb R$ ( a neighbourhood $[0,\epsilon)$ lifts to $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, which can't be written $\bigsqcup_{i\in I}U_i$, with $U_i\to [0, \epsilon)$ a homeomorphism)

So you can always form $E/G$, but the map $E\to E/G$ won't always be a covering map.

Now if you start from a connected covering $p:E\to Y$ then automatically $Aut(E,p)$ has no fixed points, by uniqueness of lifting, so that's not even a question; $E/Aut(E,p)$ might be different from $Y$ for other reasons though (if $p$ is not a regular covering)

Comment: Indeed, I thought that  $\mathbb R \simeq [0,1) \times G $, where $G\simeq \mathbb Z $ is the group of translations. (In fact $\mathbb R$ is a G-covering for $S^1$). Then I didn't understand your other example neither, because I don't see what space $\mathbb R$ is a covering for: if it is a trivial cover of $\mathbb R$ then the action by $-1$ is not a deck transformation; if it is a cover for $\mathbb R / G$, with $G$ the same as above, then the action by $-1$ isn't a deck transformation neither, because it doesn't commute in general with the projection on $S^1$. Thank you  for the help.

Comment: $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R_+, x\mapsto |x|$ identifies $\mathbb R_+$ with $\mathbb R/(\mathbb Z/2)$; but it's not a covering map, that's what I explained.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Anyway can you make an example in which $\mathrm{Aut}(E,p)$ has some fixed point, and  $X$ is not homeomorphic to $E/\mathrm{Aut}(E,p)$?

Comment: With $p:E\to X$ a covering map

Comment: I said $Aut(E,p)$ never has fixed points in reasonable situations ($E$ connected being reasonable to me) ! For an example where the quotient is not homeomorphic to $X$, you can try to find a nonregular covering, e.g. the covering of $S^1\wedge S^1$ that corresponds to the subgroup spanned by $a$ in the free group on generators $a,b$ : it's not normal, hence the associated covering is not regular, hence the quotient is not the base space.

Comment: In that case the automorphism group is trivial, right?

Comment: Another question: if a covering corresponds to a subgroup that isn't normal itself but contains a normal subgroup, then we have a not trivial automorphism group right?

Comment: No, $\pi_1$ acts nontrivially by automorphisms so the automorphism group isn't trivial. But it doesn't act transitively on fibers.

Comment: Can you please make an example of nontrivial deck transformation of the covering of $ S^1\wedge S^1$ corresponding to the subgroup spanned by $a$?

Comment: Well can you first try to draw it or give a description of that covering ?

Comment: That's the covering that you mentioned a few comments ago

Comment: Yes, I know, but I described it abstractly : can you draw it ?

Comment: https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf   page 58 contains a drawing of this covering

Comment: Actually I'm sorry I made a mistake, I was thinking of the action of $\pi_1$ for a normal covering that acts as deck transformations, here the covering is not normal so there is no such action - you were right ! there is no deck transformation (it would have to fix the point with the loop, but then it fixes the whole thing !)

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your patience

Comment: Sorry again about the mistake !